# Check if uploaded file has a specific filename

Tags: uploads

I want to check the uploaded file (from media library) for a specific filename during uploading time and move it in a specific directory, outside of wp-content uploads directory, replacing the old version of the file.

I've written all related functions from codex, but it seems that noone will work for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: try with this filter : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_move_uploaded_file/